# How do you make an image stay on screen in Processing with an Arduino switch?

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, processing, firmata

I am connecting Processing and an Arduino pushbutton. It's successfully connected with Standard Firmata. What I want to happen is that when the button is pressed, an image will show up in Processing but also stay on the screen, just like the LED, and then when the button is pressed again, the image will disappear from the screen. I'm just testing it with shapes for now. I have tested it with an LED and that works fine. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? This is the code I have:

```
void draw()
{
  buttonState = arduino.digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == arduino.HIGH && buttonPressed == 0)
  {
    buttonPressed = 1;
    rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
    text("hello", 10, 10);
  }
  if (buttonState == arduino.LOW && buttonPressed == 1)
  {
    buttonPressed = 0;
    rect(50, 50, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you've wired up your button. I'm assuming it goes HIGH when you press it.

Currently, your first `if` statement will get triggered when the button is pressed, but only if it wasn't pressed last time you checked (i.e. it's effectively rising edge triggered).

Your second `if` statement will get triggered when the button is released, but only if it wasn't released last time you checked (i.e. it's effectively falling edge triggered).

If you want the button to toggle something each time it's pressed, then you will probably need to put most of your logic into the first `if` statement (except the `buttonPressed` stuff). You will need to store some kind of value which says if the image is currently visible. If it's visible when the button is pressed, then hide it (and vice versa).

For example:

```
boolean imageVisible = false;

void draw()
{
    buttonState = arduino.digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonState == arduino.HIGH && buttonPressed == 0)
    {
        buttonPressed = 1;
        if (imageVisible) {
            // Hide image here...
        } else {
            // Show image here...
        }
        imageVisible = !imageVisible;
    }

    if (buttonState == arduino.LOW)
    {
        buttonPressed = 0;
    }
}
```

Note: I removed the `buttonPressed` check from the second `if` statement. It's only necessary if you actually need to respond to a falling-edge event. For a simple toggle, it's not important.